# Access URL query string in svelte

Tags: svelte, query-string

How should I access the the query string parameters from svelte? I'd like my script to behave differently when "?beta" has been appended to the URL.

My intuitive approach would be to use the standard `URLSearchParams` in a svelte `#if` block.

Comment: `$page.url.searchParams.get('xxx')` to get a url query param.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yep, you should be able to use URLSearchParams. In general, anything you can do in plain JS you can do in a Svelte script tag.

```html
<script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const isBeta = urlParams.has('beta');
</script>

{#if isBeta}
    <p>This is beta!</p>
{:else}
    <p>This is not beta.</p>
{/if}
```

Edit: the above method will not work in [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/), which enables server-side rendering by default. In SvelteKit, you should use the [page store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores), which exposes a [native URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

```html
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    
    const isBeta = $page.url.searchParams.has('beta');
</script>
```

This store was changed as recently as [SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.208](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3124), so other answers referencing it may be out of date. In particular, `$page.query` is no longer available since it was replaced by `$page.url`.

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchParams')` when i use it

Answer (score 49):

Here's how you do it with in SvelteKit:

```js
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores'
    const email = $page.url.searchParams.get('email')
</script>
```

Comment: `$page.query` has been replaced by `$page.url.searchParams`

Comment: how do you use this?

Comment: `import {page} from '$app/stores';
    const id = $page.url.searchParams.get('id');`

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchParams')`

Comment: @lefrost can you provide a link to this in the docs? I can't seem to find any reference to searchParams or the URL type that is attached to $page.

Comment: @thomallen I can't find it in the docs either... but [Geoff Rich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641206/8919391) cites the [this PR](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3124), which `replaces (among other things) [query] with the url object`.

Comment: The official SvelteKit docs for URL APIs is available here and agrees with this answer: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/web-standards#url-apis

`const foo = url.searchParams.get('foo');`

Answer (score 14):

For anyone specifically using [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev), a Svelte framework, the [page store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores) lets you import a `page` object allowing you to access the parameters as `page.query`:

```
<script>
  import { page } from '$app/stores';
  let isBeta = page.query.beta;
</script>


{#if isBeta}
  <p>This is beta!</p>
{:else}
  <p>This is not beta.</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: You need the page.query.get("beta") for it to work

Comment: this is deprecated

Answer (score 7):

As of June 2022:

```html
<script>
  import { page } from '$app/stores';
  const beta = $page.url.searchParams.get('beta');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A little old, `window` is somewhat more involved with server side rendering as indicated [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/mhcmv0/sveltekit_window_is_not_defined/): I think this might be better:

```
<script>   
    import { page } from '$app/stores'
    let urlPrams = $page.query.get('beta')
    const isBeta = false
    if (urlPrams && urlPrams.length > 0) {
         const isBeta = true
    }
    
</script>

{#if isBeta}
  <p>This is beta!</p>
{:else}
  <p>This is not beta.</p>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2023 using SvelteKit,

```
<script>
import { page } from '$app/stores';
const beta = $page.url.searchParams.get('beta');
</script>

{#if typeof beta === 'string'}
Beta is on!
{:else}
No beta :(
{/if}
```

Your life would be bit easier when you use `?beta=1` or any value that is considered true. In snippet above was needed to check if it is an (empty) string.